# Pagination in jpa query giving wrong number of elements in a page

Tags: jpa, join, pagination, entitymanager

I am getting the wrong number of items (different from the page size I am passing). The code is as follows,

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new com.one97.one97pay.web.dto.CustomerReportResponseDTO(cw.walletId, cw.balance, cw.isEnabled,ca.isEnabled,ca.accountLockType,ck.isEnabled AS kycStatus,cp.mobile,cp.residentId,cp.ridExpiryDate, ck.kycStatus,ck.kycType,ca.createdOn "
                    + ",TRIM(UPPER(CONCAT (cp.firstName,CASE WHEN cp.middelName is NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ', cp.middelName) END,CASE WHEN cp.lastName is NULL THEN '' ELSE CONCAT(' ', cp.lastName) END ))), ck.creationDateTime)"
                    + " FROM CustomerProfile AS cp JOIN CustomerAuthModel AS ca ON cp.customerId=ca.customerId "
                    + " JOIN CustomerWalletModel AS cw ON cp.customerId = cw.customerId "
                    + " JOIN CustomerKycModel AS ck ON ck.customerId = cw.customerId"
                    + " ORDER BY ck.creationDateTime DESC");
            int pageSize = requestDto.getPageSize();
            int pageNumber = requestDto.getPageNum();
            query.setFirstResult((pageNumber-1) * pageSize); 
            query.setMaxResults(pageSize);
            List <CustomerReportResponseDTO> customerReportLst = query.getResultList();
```

I have checked through another api without pagination, the number of results are 100+, but when I pass page number as 1 and page size 10, I get 8 elements in return. What am I doing wrong in this or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code i think * pageSize will not come at query.setFirstResult because i think you are saving the page no in setFirstResult so as per that logic write this `query.setFirstResult(pageNumber-1);`